# How can I stop maven from downloading transitive dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, maven

I have a Maven call that downloads artifacts for the purpose of running integration tests:

```
mvn -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true -Dmdep.copyPom=true -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=deps -DexcludeTransitive=true -e
```

The pom consists purely of dependencies, nothing else. There are other scripts that pick up the artifacts from the `deps` dir and runs tests on them.

Now, my problem is this: Even though Maven only copies the artifacts I want into `deps`, it still downloads all transitive dependencies to the Maven cache, which is a waste of time and bandwidth (the artifacts are compiled on another continent).

Is there some way I can stop maven from downloading all the transitive dependencies into the cache?

Maven 3.0.4

Solutions using other tools like gradle or ant+ivy are also welcome, as long as they can create the maven repo layout in `deps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven has limited facilities to control [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) and the documentation is not the best. Here are a few for reference:

- [Dependency Exclusions](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-conflict)
- [Optional Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: I do want to look for and download the latest versions of the direct dependencies though. It seems that offline mode would prevent any downloads at all from happening.

Comment: There's an option to [update snapshots](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/05/18/mastering-the-maven-command-line-%E2%80%93-managing-dependencies/) while remaining offline in that case.

Comment: No, `--update-snapshots` is a different issue, that's how often (always, rather than once per day) it rechecks whether snapshots existing in the `.m2` cache have been updated upstream. But offline is still offline.

Comment: Actually being offline I get error messages about deep dependencies not existing in my local cache, even though I do not want them. So offline is not the way to go anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like [dependency exclusion](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-conflict) is what you need.

Comment: It does look like dependency exclusion is the terribly explicit, brittle and cumbersome way to solve this problem in Maven. :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Good question.